# How to register bearer and login using beare token in one click?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, express

I want to register with become token for bearer verification and login with that bearer simultaneous.

How to write endpoint in node with function for simultaneous register and login, also how to construct frontend button?

I have following array with user for example to use:

```
const usersarr = [
  {
    _id: 1, 
    email: "aaaaaaa@gmail.com",
    password: "aa",
   }]
```

So look register and login separately:

```
import express from "express";
import { usersarr, posts, socketids } from "../data/index.js";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

const router = express.Router();
export const loginUser = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    const user = usersarr.filter((t) => {
      return t.email === email && t;
    });
    user[0].online = true;
    usersarr.splice(
      usersarr.findIndex((t) => {
        return t._id == user[0]._id && t;
      }),
      1,
      user[0]
    );
    if (user === 0)
      return res.status(400).json({ msg: "User does not exist. " });

    const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user[0].password);
    if (!isMatch) return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Invalid credentials. " });

    const token = jwt.sign({ id: user._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

    res.status(200).json({ token, user });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
  }
 
 
};
```

```
export const register = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const {
 
      email,
      password,
 
    } = req.body;
 
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
    const passwordHash = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
    if (
      usersarr.filter((t) => {
        return t.email === email || (t.password === password && t);
      }).length > 0
    ) {
      res.status(404).json({ message: "already exists user" });
     } else {
      usersarr.push({
        _id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000),
        email,

        password: passwordHash,
  
      });
      res.status(201).json({
        data: usersarr.filter((t) => {
          return t.email === email && t;
        })[0],
      });

     }
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: "dddddd" });
  }
  req.app.get("socketio").emit("message_from_register");
};
```

I tried to write on my own that code but I am new to this problem